# Is WebRTC suitable for a 30 to one connection?

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I have an application in which around 30 clients connect to a single host via WebRTC and provide their streams, the host can see all of their streams, but the clients themselves cannot see any streams. Would WebRTC be capable of this for around 30-40 clients?

Comment: Yes. But it depends on what exactly you're streaming on these connections, and the bandwidth of the host, whether it's *suitable*.

Comment: Declare - Define the QoS

Comment: The stream is just a media stream (screenshare)

Comment: RTC is one to one only, so for this you'd have the host to emit a new RTC connection per consumer...  For broadcasting (one to many), use a serverside gateway that will convert your rtc stream to something the consumers can read. There are many projects out there that do this these days. A simple search on the web should lead you to it.